# How to pass const useState("") between functions

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to pull the const ChatLog out of the main function Chats and insert it as a component or outside of the Chats function for now. The Problem is that the ChatLog needs the useState variables [msg, sendMsg] (..) that are called in the Chats function. How could I do this anyway? Am new to react.

```
function Chats() {

const [msg, sendMsg] = useState("");
const [msgs1, sendMsgAll] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    onValue(ref(database), (snapshot) => {
    sendMsgAll([]);

    const data = snapshot.val();          
        if (data !== null) {
            Object.values(data).map((msg) => {
                sendMsgAll((oldArray) => [...oldArray, msg]);         
        });
        }
    });
}, [])

const ChatLog = () => {
    return (
    <div>
    {msgs1.map((msg) => (
        <div className="chat-log">
                <p align = {checkSide(msg.usr)}>
                <h2>{msg.msg}</h2>
                <h4>User: {msg.usr}</h4>
                <h4>Time: {convertUnix(msg.time)}</h4>
                <button>update</button>
                <button>delete</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div className="ChatView">
    <p><ChatLog /></p>
    <p>{ChatInput()}</p>
    </div>
    )
```

};

Comment: It already has access to them, they're closed over (although you shadow the `msg` state with the `map` callback parameter). But nesting a component in a component like that is a bit weird, why not a separate component which accepts _props_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add props to ChatLog component. Check this...

```
 const ChatLog = (props) => {
    const {msg1} = props
    return (
    <div>
    {msgs1.map((msg) => (
        <div className="chat-log">
                <p align = {checkSide(msg.usr)}>
                <h2>{msg.msg}</h2>
                <h4>User: {msg.usr}</h4>
                <h4>Time: {convertUnix(msg.time)}</h4>
                <button>update</button>
                <button>delete</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )
}
```

However,you need add props to component when you use it. Something like this...

```
return (
   <div className="ChatView">
     <p><ChatLog msg1={msg1} /></p>
     <p>{ChatInput()}</p>
   </div>
)
```

One more thing, when you declaring a component, it has to be declared of another component. Like this

```
//this is ChatLog component
const ChatLog = (props)=>{
   return <div/>
}

//this is Chats component
const Chats = ()=>{
   return (
      <div>
        <ChatLog {...props}/>
      </div>
  )
}
```